# Why is this getting out of the line?

Tags: css

How to make the "specialLi" aligned? By making li items inline-block its working but why?

Current Output:

```
                                                             About Menu Contact
Goumet au Catering
```

Desired:

```
Goumet au Catering                                           About Menu Contact
```

I'm very new to web dev and I can't properly understand css basic things, what are some good resources that will help me get on the right track?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bar {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #333;
}

.navigation {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid darkred;
}

.navigation li {
  /*float: right;*/
  border: 2px solid hotpink;
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navigation li a {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navigation li a:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}

#specialLi {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav class="bar">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li id="specialLi"><a id="specialLi" href="#"> Goumet au Catering </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Menu </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Compared to display: inline, the major difference is that display: inline-block allows to set a width and height on the element.
Also, with display: inline-block, the top and bottom margins/paddings are respected, but with display: inline they are not.

Source: [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Youre facing multiple issues here.

**Duplicated id `specialLi`:**

Your id `specialLi` is used twice, id's are supposed to be unique tho.
Theres no need to do that, its enough to put the id on the `li`. If you need to target the `a` inside that `li` just use `li#specialLi a` as selector.

**float:**

The `float:left` on your id `specialLi` causes the matched `li` element to switch to [block level behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) which causes the paddings to properly appear (which doesnt actually work on inline-elements). As you only float the `#specialLi` all other `li` stay on inline level behaviour. This causes the inconsistent behaviour.

This automatic switch to block level behaviour is described in the [float documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float#:%7E:text=As%20float%C2%A0implies%20the%20use%20of%20the%20block%20layout%2C%20it%20modifies%20the%20computed%20value%20of%20the%20display%20values%2C%20in%20some%20cases).

> As float implies the use of the block layout, it modifies the computed value of the display values, in some cases: [...]

You can solve this problem by applying `display:inline-block` to *all* of your `li` elements to cause consistent behaviour.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bar {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #333;
}

.navigation {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid darkred;
}

.navigation li {
  /*float: right;*/
  border: 2px solid hotpink;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navigation li a {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navigation li a:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}

#specialLi {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav class="bar">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li id="specialLi"><a href="#"> Goumet au Catering </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Menu </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.